# Aggregating a row if it appears multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
| Upper_Level_Part_Number | CUM_PART_NUM | Alternate_Part | Make_Buy | Quantity_Needed |
|:-----------------------:|:------------:|:--------------:|:--------:|:---------------:|
|          AAB233         |    IEO333    |        N       |     B    |        1        |
|          AAB233         |    IEO333    |        N       |     M    |        1        |
|          AAB233         |    IEO333    |        Y       |     B    |        1        |
|          AAB233         |    IEO333    |        Y       |     M    |        1        |
```

What I am trying to do is create a selection of this data that looks like this:

```
| Upper_Level_Part_Number | CUM_PART_NUM | Alternate_Part | Make_Buy | Quantity_Needed |
|:-----------------------:|:------------:|:--------------:|:--------:|:---------------:|
|          AAB233         |    IEO332    |        Both    |     Both |        1        |
```

Essentially mimicking the logic that says:

> If a `CUM_PART_NUM` has both a `B` and an `M` for `Make_Buy`, change it to `Both`. If a `CUM_PART_NUM` has an `N` and a `Y` for `Alternate_Part`, change it to `Both`

I have tried using:

```
SELECT
    CUM_PART_NUM,
    CASE WHEN Make_Buy = 'B' AND Make_Buy = 'M' THEN 'Both' ELSE Make_Buy END AS Make_Buy 

FROM    
    BOM
```

But get:

```
CUM_PART_NUM    Make_Buy
IEO333  B
IEO333  M
IEO333  B
IEO333  M
```

I've set up a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf9ed/1) for demonstration.

How can I aggregatre if a `CUM_PART_NUM` meets the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select Upper_Level_Part_Number, CUM_PART_NUM,
       (case when min(Alternate_Part) = max(Alternate_Part)
             then min(Alternate_Part) else 'Both'
        end) as Alternate_Part,
       (case when min(Make_Buy) = max(Make_Buy)
             then min(Make_Buy) else 'Both'
        end) as Make_Buy,
       Quantity_Needed
from t
group by Upper_Level_Part_Number, CUM_PART_NUM, Quantity_Needed;
```